# Как передать regex в Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть, определенный набор полей, которые должны автоматически обрабатываться через Jquery в соответствии с регуляркой, но этих полей много, и пришла мысль, чтобы каждое поле, неким образом (напрмер через атрибут) передавало эту регулярку, но идеи реализации у меня пока нет.

Попробовал как-то так, но ничего не вышло

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.OrderOfPriority, new { datamask = "99", Value = 1, regex = "/^([1-9]|[12]\\d|3[0-8])$/" })
```

Думал в js каким-то образом потом считать этот атрибут regex, но не выходит.

Помогите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну в целом все правильно (лучше конечно data атрибуты цеплять). Осталось подключить javascript код, для контроля input-поля.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $('input[regex]').each(function() {
            $this.mask($this.attr('regex'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Возможно кто-то знает, как автоматом плагин цеплять (может что-то кроме maskedinput есть).